# How to connect NodeJS to the Ethereum network?

Tags: mist, network, javascript, nodejs

I have Mist wallet running on Windows 8. I want to connect my NodeJS applcation to the Ethereum network. I have no idea where to start. Could you point me to the direction I should be looking at? Are there any NPM modules for this?

P.S. My end goal is to create a website that connects through an Ethereum client to the network, calls a contract and recieves return values from it. In other words, I want to create a custom token and issue it to the users of my app.
This is an amazing technology!

Comment: If the answer resolves your doubt, feel free to accept is the correct answer by checking the tick mark below the voting buttons. [accept](http://i.imgur.com/GCBSWIw.png)

Comment: I am also trying the same.Please let me know the steps if you done.
thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ethereum offers a [Web3 JavaScript Ðapp API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3-javascript-%C3%90app-api)

> To make your Ðapp work on Ethereum, you can use the web3 object provided by the web3.js library. Under the hood it communicates to a local node through RPC calls. web3.js works with any Ethereum node, which exposes an RPC layer.

You can use this library as `jQuery` in any HTML page. To use this is NodeJS web3 is available as an [`npm` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3)

#### How to use.

Run your node with `geth --rpc`

```
npm install web3

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
var coinbase = web3.ETH.coinbase;
console.log(coinbase);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to run your own node, as it's not common to expose the RPC to worldwide use, as RPC is not considered a secure API.

Comment: @PaulS yes, i added some details to the answer.

Comment: BTW is there an in-browser ethereum node e.g. ethereumjs?