# nodejs 3.10.9, installation web3, ReferenceError: web3 is not defined

Tags: web3js

I'm running:

- nodejs 3.10.9
- geth 1.4.18-stable-c72f5459

I did the folowing steps:

1. run `geth --testnet --rpc`
2. installed web3 via `npm install web3 -g`.
3. run `node` (console)
4. when I am in the node-console and run: `console.log(web3);`

I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: web3 is not defined
at repl:1:1
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

When I run `require('web3')` in node console I get the same error.

I also tried to install web3 without -g (`npm install web3`); same result.

What am I doing wrong?
Why is web3 not recognized by node after the installation through `npm install web3 -g`?

I tried to do the installation according to this thread: 
[How to connect NodeJS to the Ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/how-to-connect-nodejs-to-the-ethereum-network/2585#2585)

and the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate it first. after the `npm install web3` 
in node type :

```
var web3 = require('web3');
```

then the `console.log(web3)` will output

```
{ [Function: Web3]
  providers: { HttpProvider: [Function], IpcProvider: [Function] } }
undefined
```

for more info read : https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3

Answer (score 1):

Windows Problem, `NODE_PATH` was not pointing to the node module directory correctly.
Now it works.